# Can't see why I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(…) is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unsure why I'm getting this error within:

```
//Add transition when scrolling down
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 25) {
      $(".mainMenu").addClass("scroll");
  } else {
      $(".mainMenu").removeClass("scroll");
  }
});

// add scroll effect on page refresh too
$(function() { 
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 10) {
    $(".mainMenu").addClass("scroll");
  } else {
    $(".mainMenu").removeClass("scroll");
  }
});

// hamburger
(function( $ ) {  
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');
      hamburger.click(function() {
        hamburger.toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });

  });
})( jQuery );
```

Don't think I'm missing any semi-colons or closing brackets so unsure why this is coming about?

Comment: remember that if you get an error, show the actual error in your post, too (and explain which line in the code you're showing it maps to)

Comment: Maybe try [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rcqk3hu/) and create same error in there?